# If $\alpha ^{2}$ is algebraic over $F$, then show that $\alpha$ is algebraic over $F$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field

> If $\alpha ^{2}$ is algebraic over $F$, then show that $\alpha$ is algebraic over $F$.

I have only found solutions where it shows the converse. I am not really sure where to start... do I prove the contrapositive and assume that $\alpha$ is not algebraic? I haven't learned much about the degrees of extensions yet.

Comment: Write down the definition of what it means for $\alpha^2$ to be algebraic.

Comment: So you have $p\left(\alpha^2\right) = 0$ for some monic polynomial $p$, and you want to prove that $q\left(\alpha\right) = 0$ for some monic polynomial $q$. What would you take for $q$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $\alpha^2$ is a root of  $p(t)\in F[t]$, $\alpha$ is a root of $p(t^2)$, which has degree $2\deg p$.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reply and help me. In general, if $p(\alpha)$ is algebraic, then should I let $g(x)=(p(x)-p(\alpha))h(x)$ to show that $\alpha$ is algebraic?

Comment: I don't know what you denote $g(x)$. What is quite easy to see is that if $p(\alpha)$ is a root of $g(x)$, by definition  $g\bigl(p(\alpha)\bigr)=0$, so that $\alpha$ is a root of the composition $(g\circ p)(x)$.

Comment: Does your proof still work if $alpha$ is a complex number?